# upstream connection error with istio mesh

Tags: kubernetes, istio, gravitee

I have Kubernetes cluster, istio service mesh and MetalLB. Default namespace with `istio-injection` enabled.

I am trying to install Gravitee API gateway in my K8.

gravitee.yaml (deployment)

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
   name: gravitee-gateway-test
   #labels:
   #app: ratings
      #   version: v1
spec:
   replicas: 1
   selector:
      matchLabels:
         app: gravitee-gateway
         #version: v1
   template:
      metadata:
         labels:
            app: gravitee-gateway
            #version: v1
      spec:

         containers:
         - name: gravitee-container
           image: graviteeio/gateway:latest
           ports:
           - containerPort: 8082
```

gravity-service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
   name: gravitee-gateway-service
   #labels:
   #app: reviews
   #service: reviews
spec:
   ports:
   - port: 9080
     name: http
     protocol: TCP
   selector:
      app: gravitee-gateway
   type: LoadBalancer
```

Both ran with `kubectl apply -f`

MetalLB assigns a new IP address for Gravitee service `123.456.789.11` and port is 9080, when I logged to `123.456.789.11:9080`, I get following error :

> upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection failure

What am I missing here?

Referred : 
[503 upstream issue : istio](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/13205)

[Random upstream error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60168167/random-upstream-connect-error-or-disconnect-reset-before-headers-between-servi)

Comment: Please provide some additional information about how gravitee (API Management solution) should be implemented within istio. You are trying to expose gravitee using loadbalncer service from (injected namespaces) within the service mesh while istio service mesh has a concept of [istio gateways](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/gateway/) in order to expose services outside of the service mesh using [gateway](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/ingress-control/)

Comment: @Hanx Our initial idea to deploy Gravitee in Istion Mesh and get an external IP address from MetalLB to expose services.
So I should deploy a gateway for Gravitee just as istio/bookinfo gateway?

Comment: So I have asked about you implementation details how it should work. I cant see any integrtation between gravitee and istio like f.e. ambasador api gateway) whose is working as edge stack together with istio (both powered by envoy). So if you are interested with gravitee and MetalLB you can deploy gravitee outside of sidecar injected namespace.